# "Сорок" и "сорока"

Tags: этимология

Есть ли что-то общее между числительным "сорок" и названием птицы "сорока"? Или эти слова просто созвучны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слова не родственны.

Сорока восходит к общеиндоевропейскому sroka или swroka, сорок (изначально - связка из сорока собольих шкур) связывают с разными языками и словами (например с греческим названием сорокадневного поста), но родство с указанными формами "сороки" исключается уже по фонетическим соображениям.

Answer (score -1):

На вопрос происхождения слова сорока очень хорошо отвечает арабист В фильме из серии "Тайнам нет"Русский+Араб=Близнецы Братья.Вот ссылка http://nnm-club.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?t=374523.Посмотрите.Думаю что версия очень убедительная.

Answer (score -2):

слово сорока (птица) происходит от слова сор, что раньше означало говно (вообще-то для меня,что гавно, что говно , словарь ответа не дал) , т.е. сорока сорная птица - гавноедка. А вот слово сорок происходит от словосочетания чисто русского,как и все числительные. подробнее можете узнать: http://aldampost.narod2.ru

Comment: Я знаю, что И.Губерман пишет "гавно" вместо правильного "говно", чтобы это слово не смешивалось с благородным словом "говядина", с которым оно родственно.  А Вы почему делаете в этом слове ошибку?