# Тридцать, сорок

Tags: этимология

Почему дваДЦАТЬ, триДЦАТЬ, но сорок? И, кстати, что за окончание "-дцать", как оно связано с числом десять?

Answer (score 1):

По поводу слова "сорок" [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0) уже говорилось.

"дцать" - действительно,древняя форма слова "десять"

Answer (score 0):

"-дцать" - это сокращённая форма слова "десять", и это не окончание, а суффикс.

Comment: Да и насчет суффикса - крвйне сомнительно. Вполне сеье корневоей морф. По происхождению по крайней мере.  
Самое интересное, что в словах двенадцать, шестнадцать и т.д. "дцать" признаётся таки корнем.  Поняить по каким критериям его предлагается считаюь суффиксом в остальных случаях - моего скудоумия не хватает.

Со стяжением "дцать" < "десят" тоже не все так просто. Нет единства во мнениях о аремени - а значит и о сущности - этого явления. Но это уже неподъемная в рамках форума тема.

Comment: Точно! Ясно, что -дцать произошло от десять, но как и когда?

Comment: А вот это - вопрос вопросов. Говорю ж, неподъёмная тема для форума. Либо (по Фасмеру, в частности) уже в период обособленного существования славянского или даже восточнославянского, либо по Фортунатову, которому Фасмер возражает, - еще в праславянский период. Датировка помогла бы определиться и с причинами. Проблема в том, что у перехода дцать<десѩте<dsęt и вокализм, и трансформация Ц<C нетипичны для русского. Но и в близко- и дальнеродственных славянских нет надежного источника такого явления.

Comment: Насколько понимаю, неясно даже, было ли "дцать" на каком-то этапе названием числительного, либо использовалось только в производных.

Comment: Чему я удивляюсь: у Вас 5 дел одновременно, а Вы еще и здесь пишете... Впрочем, мы уже поняли, что ничего не понятно.

Comment: В хорватском языке, к примеру, нет этого *-дцать* для 20 и 30.

Аналогично русс. словам *пятьдесят*, *шестьдесят* и т.п., 20 - это dvadeset [двАдэсэт] trideset [трИдэсэт].
Праслав. форма *desętь, ст.-слав. дєсѧть. Русс. десять. 
В русском языке звук "ę" перешёл в "я", а в хорватском в "э".

:-) Звучит в речи красиво, по-старинному, как и многие хорватские слова, будто сказочное тридесятое царство.

Даже 90 - это по-хорватски devedest [дэвэдЭсэт]. Кое-где на Западе Украины говорят дев'ятдесЯт [дэвйатдэсЯт].

Comment: Так "здесь" - одно из этих пяти. )))
А так - компьютером. За долгие годы привык не возмущаться необходимость ждать результата, а переключаться на другую задачу. Благо современная техника это более или менее позволяет.  
Другое дело, что все это по-хорошему не дела, а делишки. Когда занимаешься чем-то действительно требующим самоотдачи, ни на что другое ресурса просто не остаётся. Все, хорош флудить. )))

Comment: > В русском языке звук "ę" перешёл в "я", а в хорватском в "э".

Это очень поверхностное изложение.  Звук ę (носовое Э) на самом деле соответствует носовому Э, оно же - ѧ (юс малый). Переход в "Я" (т.е. в йотированное А) стал возможен только после палатизации предшествующего S, что в данном случае ничем не мотивировано.